# SQL - Copy data from one column to another in the same table

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update, subquery

I have a table with 1000+ rows and I am trying to copy data from one column to another, for all rows.

This is my table "Invoice":

| example1 | example 2 |
| --- | --- |
| A | NULL |
| B | NULL |
| C | NULL |

Expected end result should be:

| example1 | example 2 |
| --- | --- |
| A | A |
| B | B |
| C | C |

What I tried so far:

```
UPDATE "Invoice" 
SET "example1" = copiedData
FROM (SELECT "example2" FROM "Invoice") AS copiedData;
```

This does update all rows but the issue is that it does not update row for row, instead it picks up a random row from the sub query and applies it to all rows.

Example of how the current result looks like:

| example1 | example 2 |
| --- | --- |
| A | B |
| B | B |
| C | B |

What am I missing here?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is much simpler:

```
UPDATE "Invoice" 
    SET "example2" = "example1";
```

Note:  I would strongly encourage you to remove the double quotes!  Don't escape column names -- it just makes it harder to write and to read the code.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to update Invoice table's example2 column with example1.

```
UPDATE Invoice 
SET example2 = example1;
```

If you only want to update example2 column when it's null then you will need a where clause also.

```
UPDATE Invoice 
SET example2 = example1 where example2 is null;
```